# How to extract data from GeoJson files into Qt class object?

Tags: json, qt, geojson

How to convert all the strings of a GeoJson file to a class object?

GeoJson file example:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features" :[ 
{"type":"feature","properties":{"type":"126"},"geometry":
{"type":"POINT","coordinates":[197,98]}}
{"type":"feature","properties":{"type":"126"},"geometry":
{"type":"POINT","coordinates":[142,24]}}
{"type":"feature","properties":{"type":"126"},"geometry":
{"type":"POINT","coordinates":[185,53]}}]}
```

I need to create a class object for each string and fill in its fields:

```
class Json
{
public:
    Json();
    QString type;
    QString propeties_type;
    QString geometry_type;
    int x_coord,y_coord;
};
```

I tried to use QVariant, but I do not know how to extract the information:

```
QByteArray data = file.readAll();
QJsonDocument jsdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);
QVariant variant = jsdoc.object()["features"].toVariant();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in the following way:

```
std::vector<Json> result;

QByteArray data = file.readAll();
QJsonDocument jsdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);

QJsonArray features = jsdoc.object()["features"].toArray();

QJsonArray::const_iterator it = features.constBegin();
while (it != features.constEnd())
{
  Json json;

  QJsonObject feature = it->toObject();

  json.type = "feature";
  json.propeties_type = feature["properties"].toObject()["type"].toString();

  QJsonObject geometry = feature["geometry"].toObject();
  json.geometry_type = geometry["type"].toString();

  QJsonArray coordinates = geometry["coordinates"].toArray();
  assert(coordinates.size() == 2);
  json.x_coord = coordinates.at(0).toInt();
  json.x_coord = coordinates.at(1).toInt();

  result.push_back(json);

  ++it;
}
```

The code produces a vector of `Json` objects each of which contain information on a "feature".